# Can Molly Weasley apparate?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-transportation

The HP wikia lists Molly Weasley as a known practitioner of [apparition](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Apparition).

**Is there any specific evidence (in canon) to confirm that she actually has this ability?**

Comment: Note that merely saying "[she's quite powerful](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91237/how-was-molly-weasley-powerful-enough-to-kill-bellatrix-lestrange)" is not sufficient evidence.

Comment: They have her as being a "known practitioner" of apparition on the [Harry Potter Wikia pages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Apparition), but without any reference to the practice itself. I'll not use that as a definitive source and call it a day ...

Comment: :( She's quite powerful was basically all I had on this one ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> "But your Mum and Dad…” said Harry, pushing against the barrier again in the vain hope that it would give way. “How will they get home?”
>
> “They don’t need the car!” said Ron impatiently. “**They know how to Apparate!** You know, just vanish and reappear at home! They only bother with Floo powder and the car because we’re all underage and we’re not allowed to Apparate yet.…” 
> *Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 5

This is when Harry and Ron begin to make the decision that they should steal the car to get to Hogwarts. When Ron says "they" this could be interpreted as *they can both apparate* or *they will both be apparating*. One version has Molly and Arthur disapparating separately the other has them disapparating together through side along apparation.

There is yet more evidence, but sadly this too could be construed as side along.

> But Mrs. Weasley only smile and waved. Before the train had rounder the corner, she, Bill and Charlier had Disapparated
>
>  *Goblet of Fire*

Aside from actual quotes it is possible to infer from Pottermore and her general life that she can Apparate.

> **Wizards who cannot Apparate** (dematerialise and reappear at will), who wish to travel by **daylight** (meaning that broomsticks, Thestrals, flying cars and dragons are inappropriate), or whose destination has no fireplace (rendering Floo powder useless) will **have to resort to the use of a Portkey.** 
> Pottermore - [Portkeys](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/portkeys)

Now throughout her 30 (Bill was born in 1970) or so years of being a stay at home mum it is exceedingly likely that at at least one point in time she would need to travel somewhere during daylight that does not have a fireplace.

Comment: Is there any more *direct* evidence? I know how to fly (e.g buy a ticket) but thst doesnt make me a pilot. By the same token, Ron could be referring to *Mr Weasley being able to apparate* and Mrs Weasley simply coming for the ride as a side-along.

Comment: Ron is not *implying*, this is explicitly stating.

Comment: @CandiedMango: Oh, right. Forgot my pragmatics class there. You're technically correct for linguists and logicans, but since the resolution of "they" is completely trivial and Ron's Mom == Molly Weasley is also not exactly esoteric knowledge, I would avoid "(clearly) implies" in a non-academic context and just go with "says".

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: @Junuxx No need to apologise buddy :) any way I can make the answer clearer is welcome. I will edit to explain how it could be inteprated. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Junuxx What do you think of the rewording?

Comment: As we know now (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106986/what-is-the-provenance-of-this-harry-potter-and-the-chamber-of-secrets-quote/), the relevant quote from *The Chamber of Secrets* doesn't actually appear in the Bloomsbury version but was added in to Scholastic's editions. Worth knowing :) (Arguably :P)

Comment: @CandiedMango: Much better. I'd pinpoint the ambiguity as "they know" - do they both individually know how to do this, or do they know how as a group?

Comment: The GoF quote lists Mrs. Weasley first. This would be exceedingly odd if she wasn't actively participating in the verb of the sentence, namely "had Disapparated". It would be like saying "My six-year-old niece and I drove to the store."

Comment: @CandiedMango I recommend that you edit the answer according to Au101's comment, like saying "Alas, this decisive evidence appears only in the Scholastic edition."