# Whose wand did Bellatrix use at the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, death-eaters

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Bellatrix was relieved of her wand by Dobby at Malfoy Manor. The wand was in Hermione's possession when Harry and Co. infiltrated Gringotts. Later, Bellatrix obviously participates in the Battle of Hogwarts. So whose wand is she using? I am assuming she was unable to buy a new wand, as Ollivander's shop was closed and Ollivander escaped Malfoy Manor with the rest of them.

She could have asked to borrow one, like Voldemort borrowed Lucius'

> (which was destroyed by Harry's wand on the night Mad-Eye Moody was killed).

Draco also needed a wand, so he borrowed his mother's (in the movie at least; I don't recall what the book states). So Bellatrix wouldn't have been able to borrow her sister's wand. So whose wand did she use?

At the risk of asking two questions in one post, would the borrowed wand in any way reduce her effectiveness in dueling?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bellatrix_Lestrange%27s_second_wand

Comment: @Valorum - your link goes just to an image from what I can tell - I was linking to the wiki itself

Comment: @NKCampbell - I linked to both in that comment, but not to worry

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## She has a wand, but it's unclear how she got it.

Bellatrix did get a wand after hers was stolen. It's unclear how exactly she got it, but it isn't mentioned as being anyone else's wand, like Narcissa's or Draco's. In the movie, we see her new wand, and it doesn't look anything like any of the Death Eaters' wands.

[image]

There are several ways she could have sourced herself a new wand.

- She could have taken one from a victim of the Death Eaters (like Charity Burbage).
- She could have taken one from a lower-ranking Death Eater, it would be more important that she had one than them.
- Ollivander made Pettigrew a new wand, it's possible he was also forced to make spare wands as well, even if not specifically for her.

Another thing to remember is that once Ollivander was kidnapped, his shop was left empty. Even after he was freed from the Death Eaters, he was in hiding, and would have still left his shop empty. The Death Eaters could easily have looted it somehow for wands.

In addition, Harry mentioned that they left two wands at Malfoy Manor.

> “We left your wand and the blackthorn wand at the Malfoys’, Hermione.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)</sup></sub>

#### It's likely that using a different wand affected her dueling skills to some extent.

Dueling with an unsuitable wand certainly can have negative effects.

Harry wasn't able to use a Snatcher's blackthorn wand nearly as well as his own. He described it as making even his simple, minor spells less powerful and effective.

> “Sorry – *reducio*.’
>
> The spider did not shrink. Harry looked down at the blackthorn wand. Every minor spell he had cast with it so far that day had seemed less powerful than those he had produced with his phoenix wand. The new one felt intrusively unfamiliar, like having somebody else’s hand sewn to the end of his arm.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 20 (Xenophilius Lovegood)</sup></sub>

In addition, Hermione was barely able to stand having Bellatrix's wand, since it felt like a part of her.

> “Hermione looked frightened that the wand might sting or bite her as she picked it up.
>
> ‘I hate this thing,’ she said in a low voice. ‘I really hate it. It feels all wrong, it doesn’t work properly for me … it’s like a bit of *her*.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)</sup></sub>

Bellatrix could have also felt like the wand was a part of her, and for her that would be a benefit since it was so attuned to her. Ollivander says the relationship between a wizard and their wand is very important.

> “The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)</sup></sub>

Simply by having and using her wand for so long, Bellatrix's wand would have been more attuned and connected to her than a new one, even one perfectly suited to her, because she's had hers for longer and it's had time to "learn" from her.

Comment: Come on Bella, are you really trying to make us believe you don't remember how you got another wand? :P

Comment: I thought that Ollivander said he was made to create wands for people?

Comment: @BMWurm Of course I do, but I'm not telling anyone anything they can't find out themselves! ;)

Comment: @MikasaPinata He did say that, but since he was rescued at the same time Bellatrix lost her wand...

Comment: @MikasaPinata Ollivander said he was forced to create a wand for Pettigrew, but he doesn't say anything about any others.

Comment: Bellatrix was in Azkaban, which means her original wand must be broken by the ministry at some point. She uses a spare one, probably she had plenty more.

Comment: @atayenel Not true. Somebody must have saved her original wand. Hermione actually mentions that it is the wand that tortured Neville's parents, which is after all what Bellatrix was sentenced to Azkaban for. Of course, *Hermione* could just be *wrong*...

Comment: @BMWurm Of course she could be. But she probably isn't wrong; and I'd say in this case it's the author's (as in authors tend to do this) way of answering a question. Perhaps also she could sense it?

Comment: @atayenel Not necessarily though. And think of Voldemort: his wand was rescued by Pettigrew only to (and thankfully for Harry) return it to Voldemort when he was reborn. One might also then wonder how Sirius got a wand again; after all he was considered an outlaw too and certainly had no access to a wand maker (same goes for the other DE's before Ollivander was kidnapped e.g. the breakout in OotP). To say it was spare then is speculation and speculation which isn't always true (or certainly it is suggested it's not always true). As Miss Bella points out they could have stolen a wand!

Comment: @Pryftan What you said about "sensing it" rings true- Hermione said she could "feel" how much the wand hated her, and "all the evil things that wand had been used to do"

Comment: @MikasaPinata Yes I recall that now that you mention it; thanks for confirming my thinking.

Comment: Bella something else occurred to me. *Bellatrix could have also felt like the wand was a part of her, and for her that would be a benefit since it was so attuned to her. Ollivander says the relationship between a wizard and their wand is very important.* In your case your wand was Unyielding which meant your relationship with your wand was far stronger; that is to say if nothing else another person using your wand would have more trouble than using another's wand that wasn't Unyielding even if also won by the same person.

Answer (score 16):

#### We don't know.

The only time we see her use the wand is during the Battle when she fights Hermione, Ginny, and Luna, then Molly Weasley.

> Bellatrix was still fighting too, fifty yards away from Voldemort, and like her master she duelled three at once: Hermione, Ginny and Luna, all battling their hardest, but Bellatrix was equal to them
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows - Chapter 36: The Flaw in the Plan*</sub>

The only time the wand itself is mentioned is off-handedly during the duel with Molly.

> ‘OUT OF MY WAY!’ shouted Mrs Weasley to the three girls, and with a swipe of her wand she began to duel. Harry watched with terror and elation as Molly Weasley’s wand slashed and twirled, and Bellatrix Lestrange’s smile faltered, and became a snarl. **Jets of light flew from both wands**, the floor around the witches’ feet became hot and cracked; both women were fighting to kill.
> <sub>*Deathly Hallows - Chapter 36: The Flaw in the Plan*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So while we know she *has* a new wand, we have no idea how she got it. It could have been made, stolen from another witch or wizard, or taken from the body of a victim. There is simply not enough information available to us to know.

In regards to whether or not it affected her ability to duel. Maybe? Its documented that using a wand not your own causes a difference (Harry and the Blackthorn wand), but it is not always the case due to the temperaments of wands (Dragon-heartstring wands, for example, tend to respond to whomever. Like Draco's wand becoming Harry's after Malfoy Manor). Additionally, this new wand could have been hers now, just made by someone besides Ollivander. So again, we don't really know.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that it looks like this:  http://img.fortheloveofharry.com/2015/08/Noble-Collection-Bellatrix-Lestrange-Wand-1.jpg

Comment: Eh... That's what it looked like in the films. There is no indication how it looked in the books.

Comment: Yes. Yes, that's true. I don't believe anyone specified and I thought you might like to say here's how it looked on screen. But s'up to you!

Comment: 'Dragon-heartstring wands, for example, tend to respond to whomever. Like Draco's wand becoming Harry's after Malfoy Manor)' I thought it was the flexibility? E.g. on Pottermore my wand is unyielding - iirc Bellatrix's is too. Draco's I don't know but I suspect not unyielding. Maybe the core also matters? If it does I'm sure it's on Pm too.

Comment: I'm... not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: @amflare I guess you were replying to me but you never addressed me. If that's so what I was trying to say is the flexibility is also relevant as far as winning a wand. Of course the core is also relevant as is the wood but unyielding wands are harder to win the allegiance of and I believe the longer the witch/wizard used the wand the harder it is to win.